# how to show article's content from another view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, controller, blogs

I was making a blog and I've got problem when I want to show an article

I've generate scaffold article title content:text and I just generate new controller called **welcome** with a view called **homepage**. I created new controller+view just to show articles. for this part I did not find the problem and then I created a new controller called **post** with a view called **show** is intended only to show the contents of the selected articles from the **homepage**.

how to show article's content from another view ?
I just added `@article = Article.find(params[:id])` to post_controller
and then when I click an article's title in **homepage** I got error like this

> Couldn't find Article with 'id'=

did I miss some code?

so this is my **welcome_controller**

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def homepage
    @articles = Article.all
  end
end
```

**welcome/homepage.html.erb**

```
<div class="post-preview">
   <% @articles.each do |article|%>
     <h2 class="post-title"><%= link_to article.title, welcome_show_path %></h2>                    
     <%= truncate article.content, length: 160 %>
     <hr>
   <% end %>    
</div>
```

**post/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="post-heading">
   <h1><%= @article.title %></h1>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
   <p><%= @article.content %></p>
</div>
```

**post_controller**

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
  get 'welcome/homepage'
  get 'post', to: 'post#show'
  root 'welcome#homepage'
end
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your link:
`<h2 class="post-title"><%= link_to article.title, welcome_show_path %></h2>`

`welcome_show_path` needs an id. Try `welcome_show_path(id: article.id)`.

`<h2 class="post-title"><%= link_to article.title, welcome_show_path(id: article.id) %></h2>`

If that doesn't work, try: `post_show_path(id: article.id)`.

Comment: it work.! I don't know it should be added `id: article.id` thx anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 Controllers:

`Article` => generated by scaffolding, it means with predefined routes.
`Welcome` => only one method, called `homepage`
`Post` => only one method, called `show`.

Routes:

```
resources :articles      ##generate default routes
get 'welcome/homepage'   ##generate only one route, URL would be -> homepage_welcome_path.
get 'post', to: 'post#show' ##it will call show method without any parameter.
root 'welcome#homepage'
```

First: 
get 'photos/:id', to: 'photos#show'

In your `homepage.html.erb`

```
<h2 class="post-title"><%= link_to article.title, welcome_show_path %></h2>  

welcome_show_path ## expect show method in welcome controller, which is not exist.
```

Second:

To call show method of articles, you must pass ID of that article.

```
get 'articles/:id', to: 'articles#show' ##This route is already defined as you have `resource articles`. URL would be articles_path for the same.
```

Replace in homepage.html.erb

```
<h2 class="post-title"><%= link_to article.title, articles_path(id: article.id) %></h2>
```